# Identifying Uniform buffer in a GLSL shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I use [glGetActiveUniform](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetActiveUniform.xhtml) to query uniforms from the shaders.But I also use uniform buffers (regular and std140).Querying them returns an arrays with the primitive type of the uniform in the buffer.But I need a way to identify those are uniform buffers and not uniforms. 
Examples of uniform buffers in a shader:

```
layout(std140, binding = LIGHTS_UBO_INDEX) uniform LightsBuffer {

   LightInfo  lights[MAX_LIGHTS];

};
```

Is it possible to query only buffers from GLSL shader?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you actually have here is a uniform block. It has a name, but no type; its members (which are uniforms) have types, and I think that is what you are actually describing.

It is a pretty important distinction because of the way program introspection works. Using OpenGL 4.3+ (or [`GL_ARB_program_interface_query`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/program_interface_query.txt)), you will find that you cannot query a type for `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK` interfaces.

`glGetActiveUniformBlockiv (...)` can be used to query information about the uniform block, but "`LightsBuffer`" is still a block and not a buffer. By that I mean even though it has an attribute called `GL_BUFFER_BINDING`, that is really the binding location of the uniform block and not the buffer that is currently bound to that location. Likewise, `GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE` is the size of the data required by the uniform block and not the size of the buffer currently bound.

Comment: My hack was to search for '[' char of the uniform array included in the block.But well,I would really want to be able to id the whole block as a Uniform buffer.

Comment: @MichaelIV: Uniform blocks don't have array subscripts. What you're finding is the uniform array inside the uniform block. I assume you mean `lights[...].`?

Comment: Yeah.Again,I completely understand what you mean.But It would be nice to query uniform blocks as entities  to do auto parsing of all the uniforms and their types to construct appropriate structures on the client.For example I query all the (active uniforms) from a shader to construct appropriate uniform structures in my ShaderProgram object.With UBOs this is trickier as I can't deduce from the uniform block what it's size in memory,and type of buffer etc...

Comment: @MichaelIV: If you target GL 4.3, it shouldn't be too hard. I'll see if I can throw together a sample program later tonight. You can enumerate all of the active uniforms within a uniform block pretty easily, and I think that will do what you want.

Comment: I generally target 4.3 and I think I can do that stuff partially if I use buffer block and not uniform block.But I currently can't go into buffer blocks as I need to support backward .